# How to get json data from url to Text Composable?

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-jetpack-compose

How can I fetch json from url and add it's data to a Text Composable in Jetpack Compose

Here is json file
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
@Composable
fun Api(){
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LocalContext.current)
    val url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,null,
        { response ->
            val title = response.getString("title")
            print(title)
        },
        { error ->
            print(error.localizedMessage)
        })
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the data however you want to inside a viewmodel. Then, store it in a variable, like `var data by mutableStateOf("")`

Then access this variable through the viewmodel from your text Composable. Updating this variable like a normal string will trigger recompositions

EDIT BASED ON THE COMMENT BELOW:-

Although it is not necessary to store it in a viewmodel, it is the recommended best practice. You can also store the state inside your normal activity class or even the Composable using `remember`(not recommended for important state storage)

However, by viewmodel, I just meant,

```
class mViewModel: ViewModel(){
var data by mutableStateOf("")
private set //only viewmodel can modify values

fun onLoadData(){
data = //json extraction logic
}

fun onDataChange(newData: String){
data = newData
}
 
}
```

Then, in your activity,

```
class mActiviry: AppCompatActivity(){
val vm by viewmodels<mViewModel>() //See docs for better approaches of initialisation

//...
setContent {
     Text(vm.data)
}
}
```

Done

Edit:-

Alternately, ditch the `onDataLoad()`

```
class mViewModel: ViewModel(){
var data by mutableStateOf("")
private set //only viewmodel can modify values

init{
data = // code from the "Api" method in your question
}

fun onDataChange(newData: String){
data = newData
}
 
}
```

Comment: Actually I am learning Jetpack Compose and Kotlin so I don't know much about viewmodel. I managed to make an API call and log the data but I don't know about viewmodel so can you please give some examples of viewmodel.

Comment: I have added my api logic in the Question please see it and I want to know how can I add output data to a  Text Composable

Comment: You should really read the docs sir. You are using an ```@Composable``` annotation for a regular function...? Do you know how to extract the thing that you want into a string?

Comment: If you can, then move this logic to the ```onLoadData()``` method inside your viewmodel. Then assign the string to the ```data``` variable inside the same method. If you want to ask "How to extract a string from the url", that will be a separate question, with separate tags

Comment: Ok. You can also ditch the ```onLoadData()``` method. Instead, create an ```init``` block and move the extraction logic to that point. For example, inside your viewmodel, use this

Comment: I'm not a sir I'm a 15 year student who is trying to learn Jetpack Compose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234751/discussion-between-abinash-kumar-and-marsk).